# Why is the length of my pandas dataframe larger than my CSV file's row count?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, kaggle

So I downloaded this dataset from kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/arnabchaki/tripadvisor-reviews-2023

The CSV file has 147577 rows. The pandas dataframe, however, has a length of 147581. What could be the reason for that, or am I misunderstanding something?

So I created a data frame using pandas and tried to print its length which, I thought, should equal the number of rows in the CSV file.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\marcel\Documents\New_Delhi_reviews.csv")

print(len(df))
```

The output is:

```py
147581
```

Comment: You might want to check that again. `wc -l New_Delhi_reviews.csv` gives `147582`.

Comment: Excel shows it has 147582 rows including the header row so pandas is correct. How are you getting count of 147577 rows?

Comment: There are duplicates. `df.drop_duplicates()` reduces to 147444. The web page says there are 147410 unique reviews. So more scrubbing may be needed.

Comment: @CodeMonkey I got that by scrolling down to the last cell filled with information, which was 147577 for me.

Comment: You have 5 [paragraph separator](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2029/index.htm) character (U+2029). Maybe it can explain the difference with your editor.